# How to check unique values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table named `Bank` that contains a `Bank_Values` column. I need a calculated `Bank_Value_Unique` column to shows whether each `Bank_Value` exists somewhere else in the table (i.e. whether its count is greater than 1).

I prepared this query, but it does not work. Could anyone help me with this and/or modify this query?

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN NULLIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(Bank_Value)), '') = 
            (SELECT Bank_Value
            FROM [Bank] 
            GROUP BY Bank_Value
            HAVING COUNT(*) = 1) 
        THEN '0' ELSE '1' 
    END AS Bank_Key_Unique
FROM [Bank]
```

Comment: This is clearly not MySQL. Is it Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: What does `select Bank_Value from [Bank] group by Bank_Value` on its own return?

Comment: A [mcve] would make things clearer.

Comment: Yes Microsoft SQL.

Comment: I forget to include there count(Bank_Value) in select, so it will return counts there

Answer (score 0):

A windowed count should work:

```
SELECT
    *,
    CASE 
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Bank_Value)
        WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END AS Bank_Value_Unique
FROM
    Bank
;
```

Answer (score 0):

It works also, but I found solution also:

```
select CASE WHEN NULLIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(Bank_Value)),'') = 
       (select Bank_Value 
       from Bank 
       group by Bank_Value
       having (count(distinct Bank_Value) > 2 )) THEN '1' ELSE '0' END AS 
       Bank_Value_Uniquness
from Bank
```

It was missing "distinct" in having part.